# What's the right way to look at this permutations problem?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I'm having trouble with this problem. It seems very simple. Here it is exactly:

> Obtain the number of three–letter permutations possible for the group
>   of letters shown.
>
> S, E, V, E, N

Except there is a repeated letter E there so you can't just do a P(5,3) to get the answer, right? Or you'll end up over-counting, no? Where am I going wrong?

The answer given is P(5,3). But that doesn't seem right to me.

I would appreciate someone giving me some educated feedback on this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an intuitive approach to finding the answer:

There are $P(4,3)$ ways to choose letters including zero or one E.  If you choose two Es, there are three positions the non-E letter can fall into, and three choices, so you have $3\times3$ ways of picking two Es and a third letter.  Thus the answer is $P(4,3)+3\times3=4\cdot3\cdot2+9=33\neq 60=P(5,3)$.

Comment: Exactly that was my answer.